# Does BigQuery have a safe navigation operator?

Tags: google-bigquery, null, operators, safe-navigation-operator

Does BigQuery have a [safe navagation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#Rust), i.e. a null-safe variant of its [field navigation operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#field_access_operator)?

Ideally I'm looking for an operator akin to `?.` in Swift/TypeScript, `&.` in Ruby, etc., but a function I could call would suffice as well.

Right now my query looks like:

```sql
SELECT a.b.c.d.e
FROM myTable AS a
WHERE
    a.b IS NOT NULL
  && a.b.c IS NOT NULL
  && a.b.c.d IS NOT NULL
  && a.b.c.d.e = "my desired value"
```

*Edit:* This doesn't actually work.

> Name b not found inside a at [12:34]

I'd wish it could be something like:

```sql
SELECT a.b.c.d.e
FROM myTable AS a
WHERE a?.b?.c?.d?.e = "my desired value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no safe navigation operator for *STRUCT* type in bigquery.

What I can come up with is to convert nested *STRUCT* type to *JSON* type and utilize json path with which you can navigate safely.

```sql
WITH myTable AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('my_desired_value' AS e) AS d) AS c) AS b
)
SELECT TO_JSON(b).c.d.e, --
       TO_JSON(b).f.d.e, -- non-existing path
       -- b.f.d.e  --> error - Field name f does not exist ...
  FROM myTable AS a;
```

[image]

To check field path of struct type, you can use *INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS*.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM `your-project.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
 WHERE table_name = 'myTable';
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great, I’ll give that a shot tomorrow. Out of curiosity, do you know how to check if a struct contains a particular field name? I scoured the docs but couldn’t find anything. I’m interested in comparing how the tedious manual checks compare in performance to converting to json like this.

Comment: @Alexander, I think you can use *INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS*

Comment: Cool, thanks! I’ll get back to you tomorrow :D

Comment: I needed to do some casting, but I got a syntactically correct query with: `STRING(TO_JSON(a).b.c.d.e) = 'desire value'`. But as I feared, it's outstandingly slow, I can't get a single query to finish :/

Comment: just curious, assuming that you know the field path in advance, does it work efficiently with it instead of using json path ?